# TTY Terminal in HDMI mode

Tags: 11.10, command-line, hdmi

Today I was going to open a tty (tty1 by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1) and since I am using HDMI somehow the monitor lost signal (The TV monitor appeared blue saying No Signal). The only way to fix it was going back to tty7 (The GUI version of tty1). This does not happen in VGA only in HDMI. How can I see the tty terminals (tty1 to tty6) in HDMI mode. I am using a TV monitor with 1080 capabilities.

NOTE: As mentioned by tumbleweed I am indeed using the Nvida proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may be using a proprietary graphics driver that doesn't support KMS (kernel mode switching). The free ones all do.

Comment: Totally true tumbleweed. Thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible for proprietary drivers to do KMS, that would dig too deep into the kernel, and require the driver to be GPL